# /bin/python: No module named typing; 'pip' is a package and cannot be directly executed

Tags: server, centos

```
[root@VM-4-13-centos ~]#  python -m pip install Django
/bin/python: No module named typing; 'pip' is a package and cannot be directly executed
[root@VM-4-13-centos ~]# sudo apt install python-pip python3-pip
sudo: apt: command not found
[root@VM-4-13-centos ~]# sudo yum install python-pip python3-pip
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Repository epel is listed more than once in the configuration
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Package python2-pip-8.1.2-14.el7.noarch already installed and latest version
Package python3-pip-9.0.3-8.el7.noarch already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
[root@VM-4-13-centos ~]#  python -m pip install Django
/bin/python: No module named typing; 'pip' is a package and cannot be directly executed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Try running `pip install Django`
2. Or upgrade python to 3.* something and then try `python[version] -m pip install Django`

Or here is the answer which I find helpful

I had the same issue and none of the previous answers solved it for me.

The error appeared when I uninstalled and reinstalled python to my PC. As it appears the previously existing version of pip wasn't completely removed and when I was trying to import it with `python -m pip install package` it was actually trying to call the previous version.

To solve it first **manually delete** the pip folders in the following locations:

```
C:\Users\username\pip
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\pip
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python**\lib\site-packages\pip***
C:\Python**\pip
```

Then download [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py).

Finally, navigate to the folder where you downloaded it and run:

```
python get-pip.py
```

This procedure should reinstall pip and fix the issue.